# Let span/font fill out as much place as possible without overflowing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a header-div that takes up a smaller part of the viewport, 100% width and about 20% height.
In this header-div, I have a span with the title of my website: And I'd like that span to take up as much space as possible, without overflowing or breaking into multiple lines.
Basically: If it can scale to 100% height of the parent container (margin/padding included) without the width becoming bigger than the parent container's, let it scale up. Otherwise, let it scale up to 100% of the parent's width, and the according amount of height.
Optimally, if the second situation is the case, the parent container should scale down to the height of the span, too.

A small paint example:
[image]

As you can see, in the first example (Probably a normal computer screen), the text scales up as much as it can without getting disproportioned: It takes up all the height of the parent container, and an according amount of width.

The second example, most likely a mobile-phone, shows that if the text were to scale up to 100% of the parent's width, it'd overflow: Thus, the width will be set to 100% instead of the height, and the height will adapt.

The last example is the improved version of the second: Since the font won't take up all the height of the parent container, it'd be optimal of the parent container could adapt it's height to the child.

Also: On big screens such as a computer screen, the first example has to be applied imperatively, otherwise the text would become way too big.

I looked around on stackoverflow and could not find an exact answer to such a question. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have a look over `SVG` text

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Well, changing font-size is actually good enough for my purposes, but I don't see how svg text will help with the "conditional" cases I described above? In any case, thanks for your answer.

Comment: With pure css `font` you can't reach your requirement.  Where in `SVG` may address the need.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Okay, thanks. Still, I am not exactly sure how I would use svg text to solve my problem? Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: This will help you http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/DKcad

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Weird, I only have two checkboxes on there but nothing else. I'll try to get it running.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Unfortunately, I'm probably too stupid to figure out in which way your example can help me (Especially since it apparently doesn't run on my machine...). I'd really appreciate some more help! Or maybe we mean different things?